# Open two own terminals, which run two scripts and wait for them to finish

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I have a script which amongst others, gives the option to run an ***process***. I'm not talking about one executable, but about two python scripts which need to be run in an own terminal and produce output in the terminal.

I've considered `script1 = subprocess.call(["/dir/python","/dir/script1","param"])`, or the same with `/bin/bash` but this seems to run the python/bash the in the current terminal - not as an own window.

If I'd do `script1 = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/xterm","param to run bash and my script"])`, a new window opens, but then the described problem below applies.

The other conceptual problem I have is, that I need to wait for **both** scripts. So if calling the subprocess would work, it'd wait when the first is called until it's done, then start the second, but they need to run simultaneously.

How do I start two **new** terminals, each starting a specified script?

Comment: You tell a terminal program to run the script instead of bash to run the script (or you tell a terminal to run bash to run the script). Note however that unless the scripts wait for input at the end the terminal window will exit and close immediately when the script finishes. Why do these scripts need their own terminals?

Comment: True, I'd need to have the first script open two terminal program `xterm` (or whatever), which run `bash`, which again runs `python scrip1` and the same for `python script2`.. They'll take a few days, or even weeks - and having their own terminal allows me to monitor the progress and errors.

Comment: So would having them go to their own log files though. And if the scripts are directly executable (shebang line and execute bit set) then the terminal can run them directly. I would just run them logged to their own files from one script and tail the logs in two windows manually.

Comment: alright then.. if I'd have them just log to a file, how would I *run both* and *wait for both*? And restrict the log file to a specified size/line count?

Comment: The same way you would need to do that if you had them running in two terminals. You run them in the background and use the `wait` built-in to have the shell wait for the background processes to end.

Comment: would you write an answer with this information you gave me and maybe add a suggestion how to restrict the log file size/line count, so I can accept the answer.. thanks @EtanReisner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run commands and wait for them to finish you run them in the background and then use the shell `wait` built-in to tell the shell to wait for background jobs to finish.

```
job1 &
job2 &

wait
```

For controlling the size of the log file see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27043327/258523) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043509/258523) for ways of doing that with applications that behave and ones that don't.