# shell - keep writing to the same file[name] even if externally changed

Tags: bash, shell, stdout

There's a process, which should not be interrupted, and I need to capture the stdout from it.

```
  prg > debug.log
```

I can't quite modify the way the process outputs its data, though I'm free to wrap its launch as I see fit. Background, piping the output to other commands, etc, that's all a fair game. The process, once started, must run till the end of times (and can't be blocked, say, waiting for a fifo to be emptied). The writing isn't very fast, and the file can be cut at arbitrary place, if it exceeds predefined size.

Now, the problem is the log would grow to fill all available space, and so it must be rotated, oldest instances deleted/overwritten. And now there's the problem...

If I do

```
   mv debug.log debug.log.1
```

the file `debug.log` vanishes forever while `debug.log.1` keeps growing.

If I do

```
   cp debug.log debug.log.1
   rm debug.log
```

the file `debug.log.1` doesn't grow, but `debug.log` vanishes forever, and all consecutive output from the program is lost.

Is there some way to make the stdout redirect behave like typical log writing - if the file vanished, got renamed or such, create it again?

(this is all working under busybox, so lightweight solutions are preferred.)

Comment: "Typical log writing" as you put it has the application close and re-open the log file.

Comment: You can try to copy and truncate the file in place (not mv or rm). `cp debug.log debug.log.1; : > debug.log`

Comment: @EtanReisner: Truncation will work. Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application in question holds the log file open all the time and cannot be told to close and re-open the log file (as many applications can) then the only option I can think of is to truncate the file in place.

Something like this:

```
cp debug.log debug.log.1
: > debug.log
```

Comment: dear god, `cp` is evil. It renames the file, then creates a new copy under the old name, attaching the write process to the new one. Well, nothing I can't get around, truncate the new, rename the old, rename the new...

Comment: @SF. Yes, `cp` is odd. There might be flags you can use to make it work. Alternatively `install` might work better for you (oddly enough).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the split command or any other command which reopens a new file

`prg | split --numeric-suffixes --lines=100 debug.log.`

The reason is, that the redirected file output is sent to a file handle, not the file name.
So the process has to close the file handle and open a new one.

You may use rotatelogs to do it in Apache HTTPD style, if you like:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

In bash style, you can use a script:

```
fn='debug.log'
prg | while IFS='' read in; do
    if ...; then # time or number of lines read or filesize or ...
        i=$((i+1))
        mv "$file" "$fn.$i" # rename the file
        > "$file" # make it empty
    fi
    echo "$in" >> "$file" # fill the file again
done
```